# Error in GuzzleHttp ClientException when trying to connect to InfusionSoft

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, infusionsoft

Am trying with InfusionSoft sdk. Successfully connected and selected one of the account in infusionsoft.

But when i try to query any data like getting Contacts or Cudtomfields, am getting the following error.

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.infusionsoft.com/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

am working with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Check your credentials: clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri. The error is clear about it.

If your are sure that credentials are correct, then it's not a question, it's a bug.